# How do I store objects in ElasticSearch with python

Tags: python, pandas, elasticsearch

This is how my object(profile) gets created
`df = pd.read_csv(string_object, parse_dates=True, sep=",") 
 profile = pp.ProfileReport(df)`

I know I have to create an Index, I have found similar code for storing an image, I don't understand it though, its just example code.

```
client = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])

def persist_image_in_elastic(imagePath):
   //Example Fluff Code

    elasticResp = client.index(index=elasticIndex, doc_type=doc_type, id=idForReceivedImage, body=rawImageModel)
```

Comment: I'm going to highly recommend that you do NOT follow the approach here. This code is basically string encoding the image and persisting it as a text field.  ElasticSearch is a SearchEngine, not a file store.  Unless these images are basically mini low res thumbnails, your indexes will be gigantic and your responses WILL be incredibly slow. Instead, persist your images to an actual file store (like aws s3) and save a reference to it's location (it's url) in your elastic index. This way clients can load images associated with search results safely without blowing up your search engine.

Comment: I'm using aws to profile cvs files, but after they get profiled i want to store them in elastic search, the example code above isn't used I just needed something to show. @bryan60 I think im misunderstand elasticsearch

Comment: regardless of where the profiles come from, I highly recommend against storing stringified images in elasticsearch without a very specific reason.

Comment: @bryan60 okay but it was just an example, but i understand you